# GitLab API - why group members are not automatically set as team members too?

Tags: gitlab

Using the latest GitLab API, I checked the project team members of a just created project in a group...  and it's an empty Array which is returned

```
@git_repo_client.team_members(19)
-[]
```

Previously to this test,  I created a group and added members ( master permission so they can create projects in this group )
Then I created projects inside this group

why these group members are not set as project team members ? 
should I also add them via the API ? or did the project team methods are deprecated in this latest version   GitLab 7.10.1 d5c71c8

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

finally, I decided to duplicate the group members into the project team members within my script ...  seems to be 2 different sets